# select the next class with the previous class containing a text I gave

Tags: javascript, html, css, cypress

```
<div class="">
    <span>
        <div class="ant-upload-list-item ant-upload-list-item-undefined ant-upload-list-item-list-type-text">
            <div class="ant-upload-list-item-info">
                <span>
                    <i aria-label="icon: paper-clip" class="anticon anticon-paper-clip">
                    </i>
                    <span class="ant-upload-list-item-name ant-upload-list-item-name-icon-count-1" title="fileDoc.doc">fileDoc.doc</span>
                    <span class="ant-upload-list-item-card-actions ">
                        <a title="Remove file">
                            <i aria-label="icon: delete" title="Remove file" tabindex="-1" class="anticon anticon-delete">
                                                    ...
                            </i>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>


<div class="">
    <span>
        <div class="ant-upload-list-item ant-upload-list-item-undefined ant-upload-list-item-list-type-text">
            <div class="ant-upload-list-item-info">
                <span>
                    <i aria-label="icon: paper-clip" class="anticon anticon-paper-clip">
                                ...
                    </i>
                    <span class="ant-upload-list-item-name ant-upload-list-item-name-icon-count-1" title="fileJpeg.jpeg">fileJpeg.jpeg</span>
                    <span class="ant-upload-list-item-card-actions ">
                        <a title="Remove file">
                            <i aria-label="icon: delete" title="Remove file" tabindex="-1" class="anticon anticon-delete">
                                    ...                                            
                            </i>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

This is my case, i want to select the " .ant-upload-list-item-card-actions > a" when the class "ant-upload-list-item-name ant-upload-list-item-name-icon-count-1" contains fileDoc.doc

I made this

```
  candidateUploadFileButton = '#filesUpload';
  candidateUploadRemoveButton = '.ant-upload-list-item-card-actions > a'; 
cy.get(this.candidateUploadFileButton, {force: true}).contains(fileName);
cy.get(this.candidateUploadRemoveButton).click();
```

It works for a single input only for a single div class, if there two classes like in the previously example , it doesn't work beacuse it says there are multiple values

I added this picture, maybe it will help what i want to do, i want to press Remove button for the file named "fileDoc.doc" 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/voQqp.png

Comment: Could you clarify your question bit more? I can't really understand what you are looking for.

Comment: @SMAKSS - I edited the main article, maybe it will help

Answer (score 0):

Refer [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/next.html#Syntax):

As per your markup, you can use this:

```
cy.contains(fileName).next().find('> a').click()
```